# How to defined a static interface in base class and make sure the interface must be implement in derived class?

Tags: c++

It is very easy that we can make sure derived class must implement interface defined in base class.

That is pure virtual function.

For example:

```
class BaseClass
{
...
virtual void print()=0;
...
}

class DerivedClass :public BaseClass
{
// function must be implement, otherwise compiler will complain ...
void print()
{
}
};
```

Can we defined a static interface in base class and make sure the interface must be implement in derivate class?

I want something like this

```
class BaseClass
{
...
static void print(); // base class only define static interface
...
}

class DerivedClass :public BaseClass
{
// derived class must implement interface, otherwise compiler will complain ...
static void print()
{
}
};
```

I have no idea about this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: short answer is not natively, but you can document and, as there is no runtime polymorphism here, any missing print should lead to compilation problem.

Comment: Possibly a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062733/what-is-the-motivation-behind-static-polymorphism-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make a virtual static function. For the simple reason that when calling a static function, you always know the class that defines that function in compile time. Unlike virtual functions, where you don't know the type of the *object* whose method you're calling.
For example:

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void f() {printf("A");}
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void f() override {printf("B");}
};

void g(A& a)
{
    a.f();
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    g(b);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, inside the function g, the correct function is invoked (B::f). Even though while compiling the function it is not known what the type of its argument is (it could be A or any class derived from A).
Without making f() virtual, you would have *overloaded* the method f, rather than *overridden* it. Which means that in the following example, the output would be "A", even though you might expect it to be "B":

```
class A
{
    public:
    void f() {printf("A");}
};

class B : public A
{
    void f() {printf("B");}
};

void g(A& a)
{
    a.f();
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    g(b);
    return 0;
}
```

This may cause serious bugs, and it is suggested to never overload base class methods, and to always use the override keyword when overriding a virtual method to escape those bugs.

When making a static function, you *can* simply overload it, it would not create a compilation error. However, you probably never should overload it, because it may hide a bug that is very difficult to track (you are certain that B::f() is being called while actually A::f() is being called).
Furthermore, it is not possible to 'force' the derived class to implement a static interface, because there is no such thing as a static interface. Because you have no virtual static functions, you may not pass a reference or pointer to the interface that would implement this function.